# What's the meaning of the lyrics to "Stolen Innocence" by Courtney Parker

Tags: lyrics, meaning

What is the meaning of the song [Stolen Innocence - Courtney Parker](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=TXIP6DHrc2I)?

Part of the [lyrics](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/courtneyparker/stoleninnocence.html) is:

> How could you take this girl, and make her feel secure?
>   Then go grab your mates, and make her feel impure?

Honestly it sounds like a gang rape or something, but the song also seems to focus on a girl who is hurt and it sounds like it was one person who did it.

It's confusing, can anyone help explain it?

Answer (score 1):

It's about a rape or sexual assault as for the lyrics you mentioned i think they're trying to say he let his "Mates" rape her as well as he done it himself.

Answer (score 0):

His friends raped her, he raped her as well, and when it talks about the stained thoughts, it's talking about suicidal ideation. She says "impure", because after her friend was raped, her friend felt so dirty.

Comment: do you have a source for that ?